# unbound method error - Text Based Adventure

Tags: python, class, methods

I am creating a text based adventure in python. I have ready two books on python and taken an online course, so I think I really have all the basics down.

Now I am creating my items currently. My setup is

> Item->Weapon->(specific weapon here).

All classes inherit the previous.

I am unable to print the values of the items such as Holy_Sword and Stick. I am able to print them if I don't create them as classes and just use a variable to create the instance of weapon. However, due to what I want to do further down the line, I really would like them to be classes.

The error I am getting is:

> unbound method **str**() must be called with Holy_Sword instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

My code is:

```
class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, value, description):
        self.name = name
        self.value = value
        self.description = description
    def item_description(self):
        return "Your %s is worth %d gold and is a %s" % (self.name, self.value, self.description)

class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self,name, value,description,  attack):
        self.attack = attack
        super(Weapon, self).__init__(name, value, description)
    def __str__(self):
        return "Your %s is worth %d gold and has an Attack Damage of %d, it is %s" % (self.name, self.value, self.attack, self.description)

class Stick(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name, value, description, attack):
        super(Stick, self).__init__(name = "Stick", value= 1, description = "A stick...there may be potential here....or not.", attack = 1)

class Holy_Sword(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name, value, description, attack):
        super(Holy_Sword, self).__init__(name = "The Holy Sword of Antioch", value= 20, description = "A Sword whose potential far outweighs it's lack of stylishness ", attack = 20)

class Sword(Weapon):
    def __init__(self, name, value, description, attack):
        super(Sword, self).__init__(name = "Sword", value= 3, description = "A Wooden Sword.", attack = 5)


print Holy_Sword.__str__()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that, in the code you have here, `Holy_Sword` refers to a class. It is not itself an instance of `Item`.

`Holy_Sword.__str__` is an instance method. It can't be called on its own like you're trying to do here; it must be called through an instance of the `Holy_Sword` class.

(Note that it's usually better to not invoke `__str__` directly. This method should usually only be called through the `str()` function, e.g. `str(Holy_Sword)`.)

What you can do is create an instance of `Holy_Sword` and print the string value of that:

```
sword = Holy_Sword()
print str(sword)
```

However, you may want to instead consider making `Holy_Sword` be a instance of `Weapon` with specific attributes, rather than being a subclass. If the only way it needs to differ from other weapons is in its attributes, there's no need for it to be a separate class.

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the class first:

```
my_sword = Holy_sword(...) 
print my_sword.__str__()
```